# Date of birth validation in Bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetime

I am using Bootstrap datetime picker to select date for date of birth. Now I want to validate it as it has to show the dates from 1985 to 1995 so here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/4wwJy/

Here is my JS for datetime picker:

```
$('.form_date1').datetimepicker({
    // language: 'fr',    
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 4,
    keyboardNavigation:1,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
```

So how can I validate it for date of birth with above requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict use to select date between the date range of year `1985` to `1995`

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2D25A/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    var startDate = new Date('1985-01-01'),
        endDate = new Date('1995-01-01');
    $('#from-datepicker').datetimepicker({
        //other option
        startDate: startDate, //set start date
        endDate: endDate //set end date
    });
});
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="from-datepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="01/01/1985"></input><span class="add-on" />
</div>
```